# true or false about linear tranformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: V \rightarrow V$ an operator $Tx_i = a_ix_i, i = 1, 2, a_1 \neq a_2$. Prove or give counter example

1. $\{x_1, x_2\}$ is a linearly independent set.

2. Let $y$ eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $a_1$, then $\{y, x_1, x_2\}$ is linearly dependent.

Solve:
1. True.
$(*)$    $ \lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2x_2=0$ with $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{K}$
 
$(**)$  $ \lambda_1Tx_1+\lambda_2Tx_2=0 \Rightarrow \lambda_1a_1x_1+\lambda_2a_2x_2=0$
$[(**) - a_1(*)] \Rightarrow (a_2 - a_1)\lambda_2x_2=0$ since $a_1 \neq a_2$ and $x_2 \neq 0 \Rightarrow \lambda_2 = 0$ using in (*) $\Rightarrow \lambda_1 = 0$ then $\{x_1,x_2\}$ is linear independent


2. False.. i can show a counter example
$T = \begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 2 & -1           \\[0.1em]
       -2 & -3 & 1 \\[0.1em]
       2  & 2 & -2
     \end{bmatrix}$

$p_T(x) = (x+1)^2(x+2)$
eigenvalue $-1: [(1,0,2),(0,1,2)]$
eigenvalue $-2: [(1,-1,1)]$
And $[(1,0,2)(0,1,2),(1,-1,1)]$ is LI.

There are examples of L.D. cases, i dont know if what i did was right .. thanks for any help

Comment: looks fine to me !

Comment: The second question is regarding finding a matrix that has two eigenvalues, but three eigenvectors, with two eigenvectors corresponding to one eigenvalue. Then the set of eigenvectors will be a LI set.

Comment: thanks @NeerajBhauryal for your reply.

Comment: @Novice thanks for your reply.. i think my example fit in your observation.